# Is it possible to run powershell on any csv file instead of changing the file name?

Tags: arrays, powershell

Right now I have a script that stars

$inputfile = “input.csv”

Is there any way to remove the step of having to change the csv file to be named “input.csv”? Is there a way to have this changed to any .csv that is moved to the same directory as the script?

Thanks!

Would I just remove the “input”.csv?

Comment: I assume you're looking for `$inputFiles = Get-Item $PSScriptRoot -Filter *.csv`

Comment: Powershell does not care about the extension. What method are you using to read the file?  Most scripts put the name of the input files at top so it is easy to find and change.

Comment: You might consider writing a function whose argument is a file spec.  The body of the function does what your script currently does.  then, you can invoke the function with a specific filename.  Or you could feed the filepsecs through a pipeline, and invoke the function on the right side of the pipe, inside a foreach-object.